# FFMPEG - PNG Overlay every n times

Tags: ffmpeg, overlay

I'm trying to overlay the `png` over the stream every `N` time, for example, every 1 hour.

The example I already have:

```sh
ffmpeg -i rtsp:input -i watermark.png -filter_complex "overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:main_h-overlay_h:enable='between(t,5,15)'" rtsp:out
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the modulus function in your enable expression.

```
'between(mod(t\,3600),0,60)'
```

This will overlay the image at 0-60, 3600-3660, 7200-7260...seconds.

Comment: Exactly what needed. Thank you!